# Can you use a multistate life table with a continuous variable?

Tags: survival, mortality

I am reviewing an article and can't be too explicit about the data, but they are estimating life expectancy and also disease-free life expectancy using multistate tables. Their main predictor/independent variable is a biological variable that is continuous, but they have divided it into tertiles. This doesn't make much sense to me, as there's no indication that the cutpoints on the variable have any particular meaning.

Usually, I would just say to use the variable in its continuous form, but I am not hugely familiar with life tables, so I wondered if there was some particular reason for categorizing the predictor.

Comment: I know life table, but not multistate life table. The life table is for the single population. Given that covariate is continuous, apart from categorizing that continue covariate, I do not think there is any other method to use life table method. I think author(s) should use other survival analysis methods that can incorporate the continue covariate, instead of life table.

Comment: As I understand it, a life table (even multi-state) is essentially equivalent to interval-censored data on survival/state, with the boundaries of each time period in the life table representing the intervals. Respecting the confidentiality of the data you are reviewing, could you check whether the data might be amenable to analysis, say, with the R [msm package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/index.html), which allows for multiple states and interval censoring?

Comment: Thanks @EdM .  I will check that out.